# get X number of non null columns as single string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find the SQL command to do something but I don't know how to explain it so I'll use an example. I have a table like so:

```
| one | two | three | four | 
|-----|-----|-------|------| 
| a   | h   | i     | j    | 
| b   | k   | l     |      | 
| c   | m   | n     | o    | 
| d   | p   |       |      | 
| e   | q   |       |      | 
| f   | r   | s     |      | 
| g   | t   |       |      |
```

I need to create new columns that take the first non-null column from the right and kind of reverse it going up and joining/concatenating the fields.

```
| one | 1-up | 2-up | 3-up    | 
|-----|------|------|---------| 
| a   | j    | j, i | j, i, h | 
| b   | l    | l, k |         | 
| c   | o    | o, n | o, n, m | 
| d   | p    |      |         | 
| e   | q    |      |         | 
| f   | s    | s, r |         | 
| g   | t    |      |         |
```

For `b`, since column `four` doesn't have data it uses `three` as the first value. Same for the other rows.

I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure how else to explain this.

Comment: Are `j, i, k` & `s, t` wrong? Are `j, i, h` & `s, r` right?

Comment: Woops. Thanks. Fixed,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` like this :

```
select one, COALESCE(four,three,two,'') as '1-up',
COALESCE(four+','+three,three+','+two,'') as '2-up',
COALESCE(four+','+three+','+two,'') as '3-up'
from Table1
```

SQL Fiddle link [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e397f6/4/0)

Comment: Humm. So if I had 10 columns, I'd have to have multiple parts to my COALESCE? six+five+four+three+two+one, five+four+three+two+one, four+three+two+one, etc...?